# Highcharts bar chart rotated background pattern

Tags: highcharts, linear-gradients

So I have multiple charts using the same color codes.

Most of them are stacked columns, but one of them is a `bar` chart.

The issue is that on this chart, all background patterns and gradients are `90deg` rotated, which is clearly not what's expected.

[image]

*Designed patterns + gradients*

[image]

*rotated backgrounds: gradient is left to right, and pattern has rotated angle*

Any chance I can avoid this behavior? I'm aware I could redefine those with different angle, but that's not something I'd expect to have to implement at consumer level, isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the gradient in series you can a possibility to set options for gradient (linearGradient, stops) inside a color property.

```
color: {
  linearGradient: {
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 1,
    y2: 1
  },
  stops: [
    [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
    [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
  ]

},
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.color

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r512tsdz/

Comment: That could work for gradients without too much trouble but when this is a pattern, it becomes much more painful. Do we agree that this is a highcharts limitation/simplification? I'm considering opening an issue if there is no simple trick around. What do you think?

Comment: I don't see any limitation when it comes to pattern insertion, if you have suggestions on how to improve it, you can create a [GH](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose) ticket feature request, and we will look into it.

Comment: Thanks. I did open an issue there: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17417